# how to create Hipaa Compliant android app development in AWS?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, hipaa

I created an HealthCare android app using firebase, which is not Hipaa Compliant. I want to switch my app to a Hipaa compliant platform. What I found by searching is that buliding a Hipaa compliant application using AWS is going to be complex. Any idea about where and how to start?

Comment: https://kaysharbor.com/blog/healthcare/ensure-hipaa-compliant-apps

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, Firebase is not currently configurable in a HIPAA compliant manner.

Amazon Web Services can be used to build HIPAA compliant applications and follows a [Shared Responsibility Model](https://www.dashsdk.com/hipaa-cloud-shared-responsibility-model/) for security and compliance. This means that Amazon will take responsibility for HIPAA physical safeguards (such as employee access to physical servers) and your organization is responsible for administrative and technical safeguards (such as backup, audit logging, and firewalls).

The process for managing compliance in AWS looks like this:

1. Sign AWS's business associates agreement (BAA).
2. Set [administrative policies](https://www.dashsdk.com/resource/setting-hipaa-administrative-policies/) for your organization.
3. Implement technical safeguards required under HIPAA.
4. Manage compliance with-in your organization.

The Dash [Compliance Automation Platform](https://www.dashsdk.com/aws-hipaa-compliance-automation-platform/) can automate compliance configuration and management in Amazon Web Services.